# Hamiltonian after Co-ordinate Transformation

Tags: mathematical-physics, hamilton-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I have come across this problem in a textbook;
$$\dot{x}=ax-bxy$$
$$\dot{y}=-cy+dxy$$
I am asked to show that the transformation $(x,y)\to(p,q)$ where $p=\ln{x}$ and $q=\ln{y}$ leads to a Hamiltonian system, where $H=be^p-cp+be^p-aq$. My attempt at this question hasn't gone so well, I have not done much with hamiltonian dynamics, and in fact this is the first question I'm doing concerning the field. I firstly label
$$f(x,y)=ax-bxy$$
And,
$$g(x,y)=-cy+dxy$$
Then the system is hamiltonian if 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$$
When calculating the partial derivatives however, I am finding that;
 $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\neq -\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$$
My main problem is showing that this equality holds. After this what will I need to do to find the function $H$?

Comment: A simpler approach would be to note that your system can be written as \begin{align}\frac{\dot{x}}{x} &= a - by \\ \frac{\dot{y}}{y} &= -c + dx \end{align} and then use $\dot{A}/{A} = \dot{(\ln A)}$.

Comment: How does this simplification assist us in finding the hamiltonian? @mattos

Comment: Because then you have 

\begin{align}
\dot{p} &= a - be^{q} \\
&= - H_{q} \\
\implies H &= -aq + be^{q} + f_{1}(p) \\
\dot{q} &= -c + de^{p} \\
&= H_{p} \\
\implies H &= -cp + de^{p} + f_{2}(q) \\\\
\therefore H &= - aq + be^{q} - cp + de^{p}
\end{align}